# How to synchronize work on a database project over multiple programmers?

Tags: database, oracle, git, docker, web-development-server

I'm developing an app with one of my friends and it'll use an Oracle database. We can sync the code  with github but what about the database? Is it possible to somehow use git for that as well?

I assume the recommended approach would be to use a central online database somehow. Where do I start with that? Docker? We are both inexperienced in web development. We also have no requirement to make the database online(it's a university course project) so I do not want to go through that hassle if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your SQL scripts (like your DDL commands to create your tables, etc.) in GitHub, just like any other code, but your Oracle database won't interface with it directly. You can use Oracle's SQL Developer as an IDE to interface with GitHub.

1. https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html
2. https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/managing-oracle-database-code-with-sql-developer,-git,-and-developer-cloud-service

Traditional Oracle is free for academic and training purposes, and there is also a free cloud offering now as well. You can run it from a laptop, a VM using VirtualBox, or from the Oracle Cloud. Unless you need a specific option with Enterprise Edition, your best (least complicated) bet, is probably to go with the Oracle 18c XE version, available here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html

Answer (score -1):

We built a commerical tool that helps database developers use Git with the Oracle Database. It tracks the changes in database objects and helps you to commit them to Git. It might be worth takinga look: https: [www.gitora.com](http://www.gitora.com)